# What happens if I don't define cache in XML when using Ehcache?

Tags: java, spring, caching

For exmaple, here is my cache xml

```
  <config
        xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
        xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'>

<service>
        <jsr107:defaults enable-statistics="true"/>
    </service>

    <cache alias="dto">
        <key-type>java.lang.Long</key-type>
        <value-type>com.javadevjournal.data.Customer</value-type>
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">10</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <listeners>
            <listener>
                <class>com.topjava.graduation.restaurant.logger.CacheLogger</class>
                <event-firing-mode>ASYNCHRONOUS</event-firing-mode>
                <event-ordering-mode>UNORDERED</event-ordering-mode>
                <events-to-fire-on>CREATED</events-to-fire-on>
                <events-to-fire-on>UPDATED</events-to-fire-on>
                <events-to-fire-on>EXPIRED</events-to-fire-on>
                <events-to-fire-on>REMOVED</events-to-fire-on>
                <events-to-fire-on>EVICTED</events-to-fire-on>
            </listener>
        </listeners>
        <resources>
            <heap unit="entries">2000</heap>
            <offheap unit="MB">100</offheap>
        </resources>
    </cache>
</config>
```

And I have `@EnableCache` annotation over Configuration class. But why does caching still work if I change

```
    @Cacheable("dto")
```

( as it is in xml above ) to any other name

```
    @Cacheable("randomName")
```

There is no cache with randomName, does it create new? What properties does it use and where can I see all my caches?

Comment: The JCache standard tends to promote a default of creating an unbounded cache when not found. You can look for usages of `CacheManager#createCache`, e.g. see `DefaultCacheResolverFactory` in the jsr107 annotation adapters. I'm not sure about Spring's integration, but it might mirror this. I recall Hibernate suffering pains when trying to fail instead, so the spec might push too hard towards this bad behavior.

Comment: @BenManes: The spec doesn't promote an unbounded cache. It does promote that `CacheManger.createCache` is creating a cache with a bit of capacity by default, otherwise the TCK tests would fail. Since creating caches without any configuration might cause trouble, I choose to have a parameter that disallows unconfigurared caches in [cache2k](https://cache2k.org). Maybe there is a similar option in EHCache.

Comment: @cruftex The spec authors explicitly preferred unbounded caches by default. That is in the RI implementations and their contributions to integrations, such as when authoring Hibernate's `JCacheRegionFactory`. Each contribution then had to be changed, e.g. I [worked](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11953) with Hibernate to try and fix this, and eventually the Ehcache team also agreed that an empty `MutableConfiguration` was a bad choice.  This might not be in a formal spec document, but the spec authors very much promoted this bad practice, wrote, and contributed this buggy code.

Comment: @BenManes: "The spec authors explicitly preferred unbounded caches by default". IMHO, that is incorrect or misleading. The spec document does, at no point, say that a cache is by default (without further configuration) unbounded. That would mean a default cache is not a cache. The spec authors did, however, choose not to define any mechanism of resource control. That means mechanisms of limiting the capacity is unfortunately not part of the standard. So the RI does not need to have any eviction capabilities.

Comment: @cruftex The RI discussed is not a cache implementation, but the annotation support for Spring, Guice, and CDI. These were originally intended for use, as was their contribution directly to Hibernate. It is misleading to pretend that they did not provide integration support for users which created anonymous, unbounded caches. They tried to make it easy and look like it worked by introducing a memory leak in production code. They wrote bad integration code that projects had to backtrack on once contributed in order to protect users.

Comment: @BenManes: Facts, please: [cache2k](https://cache2k.org) is a 100% compatible JCache implementation and by default creating caches with a capacity of 2000 entries. Creating an unbounded cache is a default in Guava cache and Caffaine, and yes, it is an insensible  default and may create memory leaks. I came across the term "unbounded cache", which is a contradiction in itself, only within the Caffeine and Guava realm. The JCache API does not allow to create an anonymous cache. Spring does not use the JCache annotation integration code.

Comment: @BenManes: I don't want to give the impression that JCache is great. There are definitely a lot of flaws within JCache and especially the annotation support. But confusing facts and blaming does not help.

Comment: @cruftex I am the only one who gave facts here. I have explicitly referenced code from the JCache authors which they either contributed to other projects or recommended using in their presentations. I have stated multiple times that I am not describing the cache providers themselves but the annotation aspects and integrations. The question here is why anonymous unbounded caches can be created and I answered that the JCache authors had a preference towards doing that, which might explain the poster’s observation. Please stop claiming that I am attacking people by stating facts about their work.

Comment: @cruftex Alternative annotation providers are offered by [Payara](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/b263fb8b7eab9fee664cd8b0a9457ed3dc96cdd0/appserver/payara-appserver-modules/payara-jsr107/src/main/java/fish/payara/cdi/jsr107/implementation/PayaraCacheResolverFactory.java#L66-L73) and [JCS](https://github.com/apache/commons-jcs/blob/9a1402876e32602432b9dd087f31923fa121e6eb/commons-jcs-jcache/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/jcs3/jcache/cdi/CacheResolverFactoryImpl.java#L70-L74). Both mirror the RI by creating unbounded, anonymous caches (maybe apps are less portable otherwise).

Comment: @BenManes: W.r.t. "anonymous cache": In JCache every cache has a name, in case the client does not request a managed cache via `getCache(String cacheName)` it can create one with `createCache(String cacheName, C configuration)`. In the context of the users question the name of the cache is "randomName". When using the annotations, it is possible to not specify the cache name, in this case a cache name is derived from the method signature. Many parts of the standard rely on a cache having a name and therefore being "addressable", e.g. JMX support. So what do you mean with "anonymous" cache?

Comment: @cruftex I mean a cache that was not explicitly configured by the user and created auto-magically. These are implicitly named, but a hidden implementation detail that most will not be aware of as they are created silently. I was using "anonymous" with respect to the application's configuration, which lists the cache identities that are known by the user. While discoverable if the user inspects monitoring metadata, the lack of explicit authorship makes them unknown and therefore at risk of causing surprises in a production environment.

Comment: @BenManes: Agreed. So the term "anonymous" did confuse me here.

Comment: @BenManes: W.r.t. "unbounded cache": How to configure resource restrictions isn't part of the standard. So applications or integration code using purely the JCache API cannot contain resource restrictions. Examples in presentations on how to use JCache cannot contain those either. But where does the standard or a presentation promote that a cache implementation needs to provide an unbounded cache in this case?